# Show $\left |-z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right|\le 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

We have $\left |-z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right|\le 1$ for any $z$ on upper half of the complex plane. I have tried to plug in $z=a+bi$ but that square root is hard to deal with.

Comment: For which branch of the square root?

Answer (score 1):

Check that $\left |z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right|\cdot \left |-z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right|=1$. Check real part of $\sqrt{z^2-1}$ has the same sign as real part of $z$. Thus, $\left |z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right|\ge \left |-z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right|$.